# Is it valid to include the word 'xml' in your namespace?

Tags: xsd

I was provided a web service to consume by a vendor and they defined the namespace of the web service as follows:

```
 http://company.com/ws/xml
```

I'm using IBM's BPM product to consume the web service and the tooling has trouble working with complex types that use that namespace.  I'm trying to figure out if this is a problem with the implementation of the tooling or if the WSDL is invalid.  Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am rather of the opinion that the tooling is wrong. A WSDL's targetNamespace is a URI reference. There is nothing in the URI setup which cares about XML in particular.

The XML spec states that `Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.` That however, doesn't affect XML namespaces, let alone WSDL targetNamespaces.

Now, I call this a "best practice", which more often than not simply stands for "defences against crazy things": avoid the use of (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')) as much as possible. I've also seen it before - I was that "vendor" once. In my case, this "client thingy" was mapping URI segments to xml names, which, of course, could result in invalid mappings.